# How to create a master app which contains two of my other apps

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am having X and Y apps. Both having different usage as per their requirements. Now I need to create a one master app which will show the two icon of the X and Y apps. The user need to install only the Master app. The other X,Y apps need to be implemented into the Master app. Is it possible?
If my requirement is wrong please correct me:)

Comment: Yes why not ? Do you know about product flavors and modules  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need to declare two launcher activity for X and Y app in Androidmanifest.xml file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to build this two X and Y apks into my Master app.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set two Activity in AndroidManifest.xml have the :

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Test111Activity"
        android:label="test111"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Test222Activity"
        android:label="test222"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then in your launcher you will see them:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Great. But my requirement I am not allowed to install the X and Y apps in user mobile. That apks should be bundled into the Master app :( Please help.